# Send a photo from camera iPhone?

Tags: iphone, camera, email

I already know how to access the camera in the iPhone but I do not know how to take a picture then email it. Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Please ask programming-related questions only. Your question would be better suited in an iPhone forum.

Check Apple's website or do a simple Google search for the answer.

Comment: Aww, don't flame new users because they forgot the magic word: Programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're developing for 2.x. This has been covered on this thread (https://devforums.apple.com/message/39377#39377).

You can use data URLs, however not all mail clients support it.

```
NSString *imgUrl = @"data:image/png;base64,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";
NSString *mailString = [[ @"mailto:?subject=Subject%20Here&body=%3Cb%3EFat%20Text%3C%2Fb%3E%0A%3Cimg%20src%3D%22"stringByAppendingString:imgUrl] stringByAppendingString:@"%22%20alt%3D%22An%20image%22%20%2F%3E"]; [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bodyString]];`
```

If you're developing for 3.0 then you can do it fairly easily. Using a MFMailComposeViewController.